# How to change material-ui slider thumb style when it's disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am able to modify the `Slider` style using `withStyles`:

```
const CustomSlider = withStyles(theme => ({
  disabled: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
  },
}))(Slider);
```

but the `height` and `width` of the thumb is only applied when the component is `disabled={false}`.

is there a simple way to change the slider `height` and `width` on `disabled={true}`?

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/slide-thumb-size-gxb4g?file=/demo.js

Comment: @keikai added to codesandbox

Comment: The answers here didn't work for me. I ended just adding `!important`: ```{height: "24px !important", width: "24px !important" }```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Reason

The style is been overridden by className `Mui-disabled`

You can see the color will keep.

[image]

#### How to solve it

Override the style of `MuiSlider-thumb` or `Mui-disabled`

One option: use MUI className [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors)

```
"& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
  height: 24,
  width: 24
}
```

Notice `withStyles` attributes refer to the CSS API, you can use className + style hooks instead to customize the className which is not exposed by the CSS API like that

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(10),
    "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
      height: 24,
      width: 24
    }
  }
}));

const CustomSlider = withStyles(theme => ({
  disabled: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  },
  thumb: {
    // color: "red"
  }
}))(Slider);

export default function MyCustomSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className={classes.margin}>
        <CustomSlider
          defaultValue={[10, 15]}
          min={0}
          max={20}
          valueLabelDisplay="on"
          disabled={true}
        />{" "}
        <CustomSlider
          defaultValue={[5, 7]}
          min={0}
          max={20}
          valueLabelDisplay="on"
          disabled={false}
        />{" "}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

---

#### Update

For withStyles

```
const styles = theme =>
  createStyles({
    margin: {
      margin: theme.spacing(10)
    },
    thumb: {
      "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
        height: 24,
        width: 24
      }
    }
  });

function MyCustomSlider(props) {
  // const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className={props.classes.margin}>
        <Slider
          defaultValue={[10, 15]}
          min={0}
          max={20}
          valueLabelDisplay="on"
          disabled={true}
          className={props.classes.thumb}
        />{" "}
        <Slider
          defaultValue={[5, 7]}
          min={0}
          max={20}
          valueLabelDisplay="on"
          disabled={false}
        />{" "}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyCustomSlider);
```

[image: Edit Slide thumb size]

Comment: is there a way to pass it in the `withStyles`  instead of `makeStyles`?

Comment: @StevenG Yes, but not in the way you used here since you are overriding the component style with `withStyles`, you can customize component multiple `className` via props classes provided by `withStyles`, inside this way you can do it.

Comment: @StevenG Updated the online demo for `withStyles`

Answer (score 1):

```css
disabled: {
    "& .MuiSlider-thumb ": {
      display: "none",
    },
    "& .MuiSlider-track": {
      backgroundColor: "#e0e0e0",
    },
  },
```

This is withStyle solution , where user can change the styling of slider and its sub component.